# Repairing disconnected layers with selection sets using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, layers, vb.net

Has anyone had any success of repairing disconnected layers that have selection sets that have their data sources broken in ArcGIS?  Is there a way to detect this through code and then re-create that selection set?

I tried:

```
IFeatureLayerDefinition.DefinitionSelectionSet.Count
```

and

```
IFeatureSelection.SelectionSet.Count
```

of which just give an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.

We are on version 10.0 and code in VB.NET or C#.

Comment: do you mean repairing layers which have data sources broken?

Comment: yes - layers that have data sources broken

Comment: Did you check the [ILayer.Valid](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//001200000770000000) property?

Comment: Blah238 - someone annoyingly edited my question and removed the specifics of what I was asking.  ILayer.Valid will tell you if the layer is not valid but of course it won't tell you if the layer had a selection set before it become disconnected.  I'm specifically talking about selection sets.

Comment: Do you have a list of OIDs saved somewhere that you use to re-populate the selectionset?

Comment: @Kirk, isn't the OID list saved as a property of the layer somewhere?

Comment: @blah238 I haven't checked lately, but at one time repairing a broken datasource caused all sorts of collateral damage, which I believe included clearing OID's.  If that is still the case, then having code that programmatically saves (or  restores) OIDs from a selectionset to (or from) a table or file would be useful.

Comment: Well, there does not seem to be a way to access selected OIDs in ArcObjects when the data source is disconnected.

Comment: @blah238: The OID list does get persisted in the map document, you just can't access it once the layer is not connected. I also believe that on SDE, large (> 200 rows) selection sets get persisted to the database. Not sure they are saved in the MXD in that case as well.

Comment: @Petr Interesting, thanks... I wonder if it can be accessed through [COM Structured Storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_Structured_Storage)? Pretty much hacking at that point though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be no answer for this except to try to repath before you move data.  Then before changing the path record the oids of the selection set and I've re-applied as a definition query instead or create a new layer with a selection set.